# Java set non-editable? JCalender

Tags: java, jcalendar

Is there a way to set a textfield in Java to non-editable?
I don't mean not enabled as I want the user to be able to insert values by using JCalender but not to be able to enter values manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But I think you are talking about something like `JDateChooser`:

```
JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
dateChooser.getDateEditor().setEnabled(false);
```

Doing this you avoid that users input manually the date through the editor, they must to choose the date by the graphical chooser.

Answer (score 1):

try this its work :

private void dchooser_departurePropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
 ((JTextField)dchooser_departure.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).setEditable(false);
}